# Android Java Pass Variable from Fragment To Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

How do I pass a variable of a Fragment to an activity?

For instance Fragment:

```
int diffDays = 0;
int diffHours = 0;
int diffMinutes = 0
```

Activity:

```
private void testMethod(){
     System.out.print(diffDays);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of: use Google....

Comment: COuld not find a solution that is why I am asking

Comment: No, SO is not human search engine... Use internet search. Fx google started working before XXI century...  You should know how to use it.

Comment: I used it if you cannot help me do not comment unnecessary

Comment: What had you tried so far... Besides asking question here? Of course you didn't try to get activity in fragment, cast it to concrete activity or interface and use its method?

Comment: If you could read properly I am not asking to get activity in fragment

Comment: If you could think properly you will know that it is the same... To **pass** var x from y to z you need z instance in y and use some method from Z to pass x... If you need to **get** field x from y in z you need y instance in z and field x should be accessible in z fx public....

Comment: You need to show what you've already attempted. What you have so far is not even close to useful enough to critique. As an aside: use `Log.d()` instead of `System.out.print()`

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment:

```
public class frag extends Fragment{
   private int data;
   public int getData(){
      return data;
   }
}
```

Then in your activity:

```
public class Activity{
   getFragData(){
      Fragment frag = new Frag();
      System.out.println(frag.getData());
   }
}
```